# How do i query a record from a through table and also get the data from the other two tables in sequelize?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, many-to-many

i'm using Sequelize and this is my setup

```
// Event model
const Event = sequelize.define('event', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
}
```

```
/// Company model
const Company = sequelize.define('company', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
```

```
//CompanyEvent model
const CompanyEvent = sequelize.define('company_event', {
  companyId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  eventId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
}, {
  tableName: 'company_events'
});
```

And then association declaration

```
Company.belongsToMany(Event, {
  through: 'company_events'
});
Event.belongsToMany(Company, {
  through: 'company_events'
});
```

What i'm trying to get is a query that can return this or something similar that i can get the data from both the `company` and `event` table.

```
{
  companyId: 1,
  eventId: 1,
  company: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Some corp',
    description: 'Some description',
  },
  event: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Some event',
  }
}
```

How can i achieve the above ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CompanyEvent.belongsTo(Company, {
  foreignKey: 'companyId',
  as: 'company'
});
CompanyEvent.belongsTo(Event, {
  foreignKey: 'eventId',
  as: 'event'
});


...


CompanyEvent.findAll({
    include: ['company', 'event']
})
```

Comment: Nope, it returns an empty {} sadly.

Comment: share full project via github

Comment: This is my repo
https://github.com/tomgodee/stock_market/tree/develop/app

Comment: Thanks so it was the association declaration for the through table that i was missing.